# How to combine two stings in two fields C# database Linq Lambda Expressions

Tags: c#, database, linq, lambda, expression

C# database Linq Lambda Expressions

Str1 and Str2 both are string type.

In table values are present for fields Str1 and Str2

```
string myString1="abc";
var items1=Dababase1Repository.Find<MyTableClass1>(x=>x.Str1==myString1).List();  //WORKING


string myString2="def";
var items1=Dababase1Repository.Find<MyTableClass1>(x=>x.Str2==myString2).List();  //WORKING


string myString3="abcdef";
var items1=Dababase1Repository.Find<MyTableClass1>(x=>(x.Str1+x.Str2)==myString3).List();  //NOTWORKING
```

No compilation error but
Generates run-time error:

NotSupportedException was unhandled by user code(at run time)

I used ToString , Trim, Concat and other possible ways.I think str1 and str2 are not treating as string (at run-time) but no error in compilation

How to resolve this problem?

Comment: You need a string variable outside the lambda to combine 2 strings and compare it against `myString3`. A string concatenation will result a new string instead of existing one, and maybe it currently doesn't supported inside a lambda.

Comment: This is allowed :3 I didn't get any error

Comment: what type are `x.Str1` and `x.Str2`? If they are `object`s, you might want to add `(x.Str1.ToString() + x.Str2.ToString())`

Comment: str1 and str2 both are string type. It willnot make any error at the time of compilation . It makes a runtime error

Comment: Maybe include the stack trace.  That should help figure out what operation is not supported.

Comment: What is `Dababase1Repository`? What happens inside its `Find` method? And what else does the exception say?

Answer (score -1):

Use this

```
  string myString3="abcdef";
  var items1=Dababase1Repository.Find<MyTableClass1>(x=>string.Concat(x.Str1+x.Str2)==myString3).List();
```